# TabBar and Navigation Controller reset

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

My Mainscreen contains a TabBar with three Buttons. One of these Buttons opens a NavigationContoller for a flow with four additional ViewController.
At the end of this flow a popup comes up with a Screen "Gratulations, bla bla bla..."
In this view is a UIButton "Back to main screen" which move the Mainscreen to `"tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0"`
so far it works!
But if I click the TabbarButton again I see the screen "Gratulations, bla bla bla..." again.
can someone tell me who I Reset the NavigationController that the flow begins again

Thanks Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line of code when the user presses "Back to main screen" button:

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```